# Javascript For Loop executes repeatedly in Chrome plugin, but only once from console

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, google-chrome, plugins

I'm quite new to Chrome extensions and am banging my head against a wall here. I have a JS for loop that executes once in the console and works absolutely perfectly. However when I add the loop into my plugin, it loops 42 times. Here is the loop:

```
var a;
var b = 0;
$("div").dblclick(function()
{

    for (a=0;a < document.querySelectorAll("div.sectionRowComponent").length;a+=1)
    {
        try
        {
            if(document.querySelectorAll("div.sectionRowComponent")[a].getElementsByTagName("input").length > 0)
            {
            console.log (a + ":" + document.querySelectorAll("div.sectionRowComponent")[a].getElementsByTagName("span")[1].innerText + document.querySelectorAll("div.sectionRowComponent")[a].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
            }
        }

        catch(err)
            {

            }

    }
console.log(b+=1);
console.log(a);

})
```

Variable a (how many section row components) returns 162, while variable b (how many times the loop runs) returns 42.

As I said, this code executes perfectly in the console, but 42 times in a plugin. There is nothing else in the plugin to interfere with it. The manifest has only one reference to a js file and the rest is HTML5 without any script at the moment.

For clarity, here is my manifest:

```
{
"browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "encrypt.html" //this is an empty file just now
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://an.address.zul*", "https://another address.zul"],
            "js": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "theScript.js"]   
        }
    ]

}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I should add that vars a and b were only added to test the loop after the strange behaviour started.

Comment: Where is it being called to run from? What is document.querySelectorAll("div.sectionRowComponent").length from the console?

Comment: you may have multiple div with class `sectionRowComponent` exists..

Comment: hi @scott-evans, it's 162 (variable a). The caller is the $("div").dblclick event.

Comment: hello @Kiranramchandran - Yes there are multiple divs with that class, but then that's the point of the code to count through them all and extract the title and input element content from each one. It does work perfectly from the inspector, but not from a plugin.

Comment: @CodeManiac thanks :)  I have, it's 162. Which is what var a returns.

Comment: @SirBacon in that case can you reproduce the same thing ? i mean any live or running code.

Comment: @CodeManiac Sorry, I'm quite new here so I'm unsure what you mean by "reproduce the same thing." What I will say is that the error is always the same and the output is too. The live code is what you see here. I can't point you to a live page as this is being run in a UAT environment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the reference to "div" in the dblclick handler to an explicit class of div

```
$(".className").dblclick(function()
```

Error resolved. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.